# Manifest placeholders для различных build variants

Tags: android, gradle

Есть два продакт флэйвора:

```
productFlavors {
    demo {
        ...
    }

    full {
        ...
    }
}
```

и два билд тайпа:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        ...
    }

    debug {
        ...
    }
}
```

Исходя из существующих продакт флейворов и билд тайпов получается четыре билд варианта:

```
demoRelease
demoDebug
fullRelease
fullDebug
```

Возможно ли для каждого из четырех билд вариантов в AndroidManifest.xml прописать различные значения для некоторых атрибутов? Если возможно, то как? С помощью manifest placeholders или как-то иначе?

Например, есть четыре API-ключа для какого-то сервиса и в зависимости от конкретного билд варианта в AndroidManifest.xml нужно вставлять свой собственный ключ.

---

Сейчас у меня это реализовано с помощью отдельного strings.xml для каждого билд варианта, но хотелось бы где-то **в одном файле** прописать API-ключи, **а не создавать кучу дополнительных файлов**.

Интересует что-нибудь вроде [этого](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32503193/7129209) решения (в первой части ответа).

Comment: А в чем проблема использовать тот вариант, что вы предложили?

Comment: @zTrap, Посмотрите предпоследний абзац вопроса. Хочется получить более красивое решение.

Comment: я имею в виду приложенную вами ссылку

Comment: @zTrap, Тот вариант просто не работает :)

Comment: Возможно [этот вариант](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28954071/how-can-i-access-a-buildconfig-value-in-my-androidmanifest-xml-file) натолкнёт вас на нужное решение

Comment: Конечно, не мне уж вас учить как тут заведено. Но если один из ответов вам помог - следует его принять

Comment: @zTrap, В данный момент нет времени протестировать Ваше решение. Один из ответов я прокомментировал, так как по нему сразу видно, что это не то. Как попробую – обязательно оставлю фидбек.

Comment: буду надеяться, что это решение Вам подойдёт :)

Answer (score 1):

У меня сделано это так (build.gradle):

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "blah-blah"
        targetSdkVersion targetSdkVersionVar
    }
    productFlavors {
        honeycumb {
            minSdkVersion minSdkHoneycumb
            targetSdkVersion targetSdkHoneycumb
        }
        kitkat {
            minSdkVersion minSdkKitkat
            targetSdkVersion targetSdkVersionVar
        }
    }
}
```

Остальное прописано в манифестах `src/main`, `src/honeycumb`, `src/kitkat`

Comment: У Вас здесь отдельные параметры для каждого из **продакт флэйворов**, а мне нужны отдельные параметры для каждого из **билд вариантов**.

Answer (score 1):

Можно дополнить [вариант, предложенный вами](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31461267/using-a-different-manifestplaceholder-for-each-build-variant/32503193#32503193) таким образом:

**build.gradle**

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        manifestPlaceholders = [ apiKey:project.property('default.ApiKey') ]
    }
}

applicationVariants.all{ variant->
    if (variant.productFlavors.get(0).name.equals("demo")) {
        if (variant.buildType.name.equals("release")) {
            manifestPlaceholders = [ apiKey:project.property('release.demo.ApiKey') ]
        } else {
            manifestPlaceholders = [ apiKey:project.property('debug.demo.ApiKey') ]
        }
    } else if (variant.productFlavors.get(0).name.equals("full")){
        if (variant.buildType.name.equals("release")) {
            manifestPlaceholders = [ apiKey:project.property('release.full.ApiKey') ]
        } else {
            manifestPlaceholders = [ apiKey:project.property('debug.full.ApiKey') ]
        }    
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<meta-data android:name="your name" android:value="${apiKey}"/>
```

**gradle.properties (глобальный)**

Если его нет, то необходимо создать и расположить по пути `<USER_HOME>/.gradle`.

```
release.demo.ApiKey="your_key"
debug.demo.ApiKey="your_key"
release.full.ApiKey="your_key"
debug.full.ApiKey="your_key"
default.ApiKey="your_key"
```

Глобальный файл нужен только если код будет загружен в публичный репозиторий, так как он игнорируется системами контроля версий (актуально для библиотек). В противном случае можно использовать `gradle.properties` проекта.

[источник](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-build-variables.html)

Comment: Попробовал Ваше решение. В итоге, в любом билд варианте используется `default.ApiKey`.